# Bar charts with xaxis bins using Plotly or Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

[image]

This is the bar chart I have created so far using Plotly and iPython. Clearly this is hard to read. What I want to do is create bins on the x axis. For example create 1 bar of the total y values for x values from 0-50. And 50-100. And so on.

Can this be done using matplotlib or Plotly?

Plotly Code:

```
data = Data([
    Bar(
        x=[tuples[0] for tuples in tuples_list],
        y=[tuples[1] for tuples in tuples_list]
    )
])
layout = dict(
   title='Public Video Analysis',
   yaxis=YAxis(
       title = 'Views'),
   xaxis1=XAxis(
       title = "Duration in Seconds"),
   )
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Could you post some code you used? For the Plotly solution, did you use `Histogram` class to create a plot or `Bar`. I wouldn't have expected the automatic binning Plotly uses to have produced the graph you posted here.

Comment: @theengineear I added my Plotly code above. I used the Bar class to plot length of videos vs views which are the x and y values of the tuples. It looks like the binning changes to look visually pleasing for histograms  and bar charts if I use a lower number of values or a sample of the data I am trying to plot. I am plotting a few million tuples to get a sense of the whole of my data- unfortunately it's overwhelming plotly however not matplotlib. I don't need to see all the data at once, so I wish plotly's zoom in feature worked a little better for big data. I hope this feedback is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see more examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as P

mu, sigma = 200, 25
x = mu + sigma*P.randn(10000)

P.hist(x, 50)
P.show()
```

The above produces:

[image]

If you do,

```
P.figure()
P.hist(x, range(100,300,10))
P.savefig('b.png')
```

You will have,

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use Plotly's `Histogram` and choose the size of your bins like in the following example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(500)*100

data = Data([Histogram(x=x,
                       autobinx=False,
                       xbins=XBins(start=min(x),
                                   end=max(x),
                                   size=50)
    )
])
```

[image: example histogram]
https://plot.ly/~chelsea_lyn/4551/x/